# Why can't I open some web games' site?

Tags: website

When I want to play this site's game and click the link:http://wars.swagblack.com/webgamethewars.aspx, it can't open sometimes? Anyone can tell me why? Is it some wrong with my computer or just because this game web site is under maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

Going at the angle that you think this is a problem with your computer and not a general webservice/game related question.

Whenever you have a problem loading a website, if you do not have another computer on your desk you can quickly use, I recommend using [Downforeveryoneorjustme](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/). It can quickly tell you if a website is up.

[image]

It is more than likely just a problem with the site being under maintenance or heavy load.

Comment: One of my favorite services :) +1 from me.